# Remove query string from PHP URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, query-string

My url is :
https://domain.com/chapter-detail.php?board=12&class=145&subject=maths

Now, I want to remove query string from the url and I want to get resultant url as : https://domain.com/chapter-detail.php

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule to remove query strings fromthe uri /chapter-detail.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^chapter-detail.php$ /chapter-detail.php? [L,R]
```

Comment: Yes, rule is working fine but i did not get any value on that page like:board=12&class=145&subject=maths

Comment: After discarding querystrings , you cant get query values as they are not present in the url now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
```

Comment: This function used to get the url without query string data in the PHP page. but my question is, Can I hide querysting from the url

Comment: if you have url as a string then you can use explode("?",Url) function in php